# Should I throw exception from call() method of callable class?

Tags: java

Should I throw exception from call() method of callable class? If no, why not? What is the possible drawbacks?

I have a call method and in it another class is called. Another class throws exception and it is highly related with a clas which running callable method and gets its outputs. Should I handle exception in call method or rethrow it?

Comment: It all depends. What does your `Callable` do? Is it running on a separate thread? Do you want to handle that exception?

Comment: What kind of app are you making? any framework?

Comment: A Callable represents a task to perform. If you consider that the task must fail when you get this exception, then throw it (or throw another exception wrapping it). If you consider that the task must succeed despite this exception, then catch it and deal with it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it run in thread pool with executor service. CAllable class does extracting content of pdf file.

Comment: @JBNizet Please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, it will fail if it faced with severe IO failure. (Rare case)

Comment: Then make it throw an exception when it faces a severe IO failure.

Answer (score 2):

You should deal with exceptions in Callable's `call()` method the same way as you deal with them everywhere else.

A Callable represents a task to perform. If you consider that the task must fail when you get this exception, then throw it (or throw another exception wrapping it).

If you consider that the task must succeed despite this exception, then catch it and deal with it.

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call%28%29) of the `call()` method says:

> Computes a result, or throws an exception if unable to do so.

Comment: If you do not throw exceptions you can use Runnable instead.

Comment: Unchecked exceptions can be thrown at any time ;)

Comment: @Hannes not if you want to return a result.

Comment: Correct. The OP commented that he converts a pdf, so premusable no return is necessary.

Comment: @Hannes, what if result needed?